# База Данных - Словарь - глагольное управление

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Я ищу API (или базу данных - например файл .csv) для проекта, которое дает не только значения, формы и переводы слова, но и глагольное управление. Например для глагола "помочь" - API дало бы "кому, чем" (или "дательный, творительный") или для "говорить" - "кому, что, о чем, на чем". Я уже использую Яндекс Словарь API, но у них не предлагаются и управления глаголами.

Есть ли у кого-нибудь идея?

Спасибо!

Comment: Я переоткрыл ваш вопрос, однако вы навряд ли найдете ответ на нашем сайте. Ваш вопрос на стыке русистики и программирования (т. е. по сути -- о компьютерной лингвистике), может быть, специалисты обратят на него внимание и что-нибудь подскажут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-нибудь будет интересно, в конце концов дали мне вот такое http://www.solarix.ru/sql-dictionary-sdk.shtml, которое предлагает то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я не помогу с ссылкой на словари, но попытаюсь помочь с ключевыми словами для поиска. То, что Вы ищете, называется "управление". Существуют классические словари, например, справочник Розенталя "Управление в русском языке" (наверняка ведь должен быть и в csv-формате). К этому также имеют отношение термины "падежная рамка" (рамка валентностей) или "модель управления" (на днях разбирали такой вопрос здесь).

Или вот ещё [ссылка](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2009/materials/html/47.htm) из Википедии. Посмотрите, как это решали другие. Вы можете связаться с проектами различных корпусов и попросить у них словари с соответствующей разметкой. Иногда что-то подобное выкладывается в открытом доступе.

Comment: Спасибо, термины точно буду полезны! Сам буду снова искать! Почему-то в моем обучении их не было